# Prove or disprove that $J(x)=\lVert Ax-b\rVert^{2}$ is $\alpha$ convex

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, solution-verification, convex-analysis

I consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the functional given by $J(x)=\lVert Ax-b\rVert^{2}$ where $A\in\mathcal{M}_{p,n}(\mathbb{R})$.

I want to prove or disprove that $J$ is $\alpha$ convex that is

$$
J(\frac{v+u}{2})\leq \frac{J(v)+J(u)}{2} - \frac{\alpha}{8}\lVert v - u\rVert^{2}
$$

Where $\alpha>0$.

Here is an attempt : using the identity parallelogram we get

$$
J(\frac{x+y}{2}) = \lVert A\frac{x+y}{2} - b \rVert^{2} =\frac{1}{2}\lVert Ax - b \rVert^{2} + \frac{1}{2}\lVert Ay - b \rVert^{2}  - \lVert A\frac{x-y}{2}\rVert^{2} 
$$

From there, I do not see what to use to pursue. Have you some ideas or hints please ?

I am wondering if it is true.

---

### Edit

I think it is false : if we take $p=n$ then taking the identity matrix and two (different) vectors of the orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to obtain a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your work, it remains to show there exists $\alpha$ such that
$$\frac{\alpha}{8} \|x-y\|^2 \le \|A(x-y)/2\|^2.$$

If the smallest singular value $\sigma$ of $A$ is strictly positive (that is, if $Au \ne 0$ for all $u \ne 0$), then you can take $\alpha = 2\sigma^2$.

Otherwise, there exists some $u\ne 0$ such that $Au=0$, choosing $x$ and $y$ such that $x-y=0$ makes the right-hand side zero, but the left-hand side positive. So in this case it is not $\alpha$-convex.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and taking the time to help me ! However I am not sure to understand well the first remark about singular values, I do not see really the link with the singular value ? Using that $\lVert A\frac{x-y}{2}\rVert^{2}= \frac{(x-y)^t}{2}A^{t}A\frac{x-y}{2}$ but to use any singular value I should have an eingenvector associated which is not necessarily the case here no ?

Comment: @coboy I am using the following claim: if $\sigma$ is the smallest singular value of $A$, then $\|Au\| \ge \sigma \|u\|$ for any $u \ne 0$. See if you can show this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The attempt : denote $A^{t}A= B$ then by the spectral theorem there exists $H$ a passage matrix from the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to the orthonormal basis composed of the eigenvector of $B$. For every $u\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ we have $u = H\hat{u}$ where $\hat{u}$ is the vector composed of the coordinate of $u$ in the eigenvector basis. Thus we have $\lVert Au\rVert^{2} = u^{t}A^{t}Au = \hat{u}^{t}H^{t}\hat{B}H\hat{u}= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\hat{u}_{i}^{2}\lambda_i \geq\lambda \sum_{i=1}^{n}\hat{u}_{i}^{2} =\lambda\lVert \hat{u}\rVert^{2} = \lambda\lVert u\rVert^{2}$

Comment: Where $\lambda$ is the smallest positive egeinvalue of $B$ and the conclusion follows by taking the square root since all quantities involves are positive

Comment: @coboy This seems correct to me.

Comment: Great, are you aware on another way to prove this without using change of basis matrix ?